# Type error: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>'

Tags: typescript, build, compiler-errors, fetch, next.js

I have this inside an Express.js-like (it's actually Next.js version of something like Express.js) function. The url is a url that ends in `.csv`, so it is a CSV file download. I'm trying to fetch the CSV and stream the data through the `csv-parser` library (so I don't have to persist the file) and then finally into an array (I've omitted some of this code, as it is relevant).

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {

  ...

  const response: Response = await fetch(url)
  try {
    response.body.pipe(parser())
      .on('data', callback...)
  } catch {
    error handling...
  }
}
```

It all works the way I want it, but when I go to build my app I get this error on the `response.body.pipe` part.

```
Type error: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>'.
```

Hope this is enough context & makes sense. Could anyone advise on how to address this?

Answer (score 1):

I parsed NextApiRequest body like this:

```js
const d = await req.body?.getReader().read();
console.log(d?.value?.toString());
```